# PySpark Grouby DataFrame becomes unresponsive when attempting to cache

Tags: caching, apache-spark, pyspark, distributed-computing, apache-spark-sql

I have a ~60gb file with ~755m rows. I'm taking this file, and reshaping it into a feature set, which means it gets transformed into a ~27350x27350 matrix.

```
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark.sql.functions import *

schema = [StructField("_id", StringType(), False), StructField("minor_id", StringType(), False), StructField("minor_seq_len", IntegerType(), False), StructField("major_id", StringType(), False), StructField("major_seq_len", IntegerType(), False), StructField("optimal_alignment_score", IntegerType(), False)]
schema = StructType(schema)
df = spark.read.csv(path="file.csv", header=True, inferSchema=False, mode="FAILFAST", schema=schema)
df = df.withColumn("e_val", 0.027 * df['major_seq_len'] * df['minor_seq_len'] * exp(-1 * 0.239 * df['optimal_alignment_score']))
df = df.withColumn("p_val", 1 - exp(-1 * df['e_val'])).cache()
df.count()
pivot = df.groupby("major_id").pivot("minor_id").mean("p_val")
```

The above works perfectly. When looking at the PySpark Application UI, I can see the df rdd under the storage page. However, when I call:

```
pivot.cache()
```

Everything becomes unresponsive. No jobs appear, and the pivot rdd does not appear in the storage tab. The pyspark shell line moves down (like it's running a command), but never seems to finish. I've tried using `.persist()`, with various options, and tried to combine two lines: `pivot.cache(); pivot.count()` hoping it may push through, however nothing has worked.

Additionally, if I interrupt the `.cache()` step, and attempt to do anything else (`df.count()`), nothing responds.

Is it normal to not be able cache at this step?

### Update

I've tried really narrowing down the data set with:

```
pivot = df.groupby("major_id").pivot("minor_id").mean("p_val")
sample_df = pivot.sample(False, 0.0001) # this is ~26 rows.
sample_df.cache().count()
```

However, the last line sits for a long time. There's still no spark job status, no jobs generated in the UI, nor anything anywhere else in the various UI's, nothing in the logs, nor anything else. It just sits there- awake and unresponsive.